# how to pass some code to a function that accepts callback?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function from a marketing provider that needs to be executed when a product is removed from cart.....

This code must execute when the I remove a product from cart:

```
_ra.removeFromCartInfo = {
    "product_id": 133,
    "quantity": 1,
    "variation": false
};

if (_ra.ready !== undefined) {
    _ra.removeFromCart(
        _ra.removeFromCartInfo.product_id,
        _ra.removeFromCartInfo.quantity,
        _ra.removeFromCartInfo.variation,
        function() {
           // code that need to execute after the removeFromCart finished
        }
    );
}
```

the removeFromCart accepts a callback function that I need to add some code to execute after the parent function removeFromCart executes.

I created my own function (_rb_remove_from_cart) - to avoid code duplication -  where I put the code from above in it:

```
function _rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation) {
    var _ra = _ra || {};

    _ra.removeFromCartInfo = {
        "product_id": product_id,
        "quantity": qty,
        "variation": variation
    };

    if (_ra.ready !== undefined) {
        _ra.removeFromCart(
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.product_id,
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.quantity,
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.variation,
            function() {
               // code that need to execute after the removeFromCart finished
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When I execute the function  - where I need -

```
// the function that removes the element from cart href="javascript:remove_cart_element( ... )
function remove_cart_element(product_id, qty, variation, url) {
        ​
   ​// code that need to execute in callback function

   ​...
  ​
   ​_rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation);
}
```

I don't know how to pass the code to the function _rb_remove_from_cart to executes in the callback.

Should I create another function with the code .... then pass as argument to the function _rb_remove_from_cart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass executable code directly to a function, however, you can pass it another function.

```
function sayHello(param1, param2) {
    alert(`Hello! Param1=${param1}, param2=${param2}`);
}

function _rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation, callback) { // callback is sayHello
    
        ...
        _ra.removeFromCart(
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.product_id,
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.quantity,
            _ra.removeFromCartInfo.variation,
            callback
        );
}

function remove_cart_element(product_id, qty, variation, url) {     ​
   ​_rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation, sayHello.bind(this, param1, param2));
}
```

Comment: It seems to work if the sayHello has no params. If the function has for ex: url param sayHello(url) and calling ` ​_rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation, sayHello(url));` seems to execute instantly in the `remove_cart_element` .... not as the callback function in the `_ra.removeFromCart`

Comment: thx. One thing.... Why should I use in bind 'this' ? It's not ok to use it like this ` ​_rb_remove_from_cart(product_id, qty, variation, sayHello.bind(url));` passing the url parm from remove_cart_element -> sayHello

Comment: No because the first parameter of `.bind` is the context (this). You are passing `this` under the name `url`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind